# How to add pop up window in php echo?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, popupwindow

I just working with php mysql view rows from database in table but i want to make a link. when any one click comment it will be open as popup window.

image
[image]

```
echo "<tr bgcolor='#EBEBE6'>
  <td width='5'> </td>
  <td>".$rows['Date']."</td> 
  <td>".$rows['Payment_ID']."</td>
  <td>".$rows['Staff_ID']."</td>
  <td>".$rows['Amound']."</td>
  <td>"[i want add popup link here].$rows['Comments']."</td>
</tr>";
```

Comment: I dont really see any situation where this would be preferable. But you could perhaps make this functionality by wrapping in the comment in a `<a href="url" target="_blank">`. By specifying `_blank` it should at least open the url in a new tab. If you really want a popup window you could also take a look at [this code](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_popup_window_code.cfm)

Comment: Introduce lightbox or something.

Comment: Substitute "[i want add popup link here]" with a valid <a> tag and you're done? What's the problem?

Comment: i did that but still i couldn't get any solution ; because the problem is when i view data from mysql database in a table iam using
if($color==1){
echo "<tr bgcolor='#EBEBE6'>
<td width='5'> </td>
<td>".$rows['Date']."</td>
<td>".$rows['Payment_ID']."</td>
<td>".$rows['Staff_ID']."</td>
<td>".$rows['Amound']."</td>
<td>".$rows['Comments']."</td>
<td> ".$rows['Print']."</td>
</tr>";

In this stage when you click comments it should open as pop up window to show that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.open` to popup new window

```
echo "<tr bgcolor='#EBEBE6'>
  <td width='5'> </td>
  <td>".$rows['Date']."</td> 
  <td>".$rows['Payment_ID']."</td>
  <td>".$rows['Staff_ID']."</td>
  <td>".$rows['Amound']."</td>
  <td><a href='#' onclick='window.open("you url here","","width=200,height=100");'>".$rows['Comments']."</td>
</tr>";
```

Comment: Getting error in ** <td><a href='#' onclick='window.open("you url here","","width=200,height=100");'>".$rows['Comments']."</td> ** this line

Comment: i think **"** inside window.open breaking code. add slash
`window.open(\"you url here\",\"\",\"width=200,height=100\");`